# Help with converting a sRGB image to CMYK

Tags: cmyk

i have a image which i will send to a site, to get printed as vinyl stickers. The site want the image to be in CMYK (no specifik profile) and 300 dpi. I tried to convert the file to CMYK and 300dpi the last days, but it's really hard for me, since i have neither the experience or the right tools for it..

The dimensions of the stickers will be 10x10cm, and the image is in 1181x1181px, which i read is the right dimensions for 10x10cm and 300dpi.

Here's the image: [http://m.imgur.com/bsbPfiE](https://m.imgur.com/bsbPfiE) it's in sRGB.

If someone could convert it to CMYK and 300 dpi, that would be great. Save it as a .tiff

Comment: This is a request for free work, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

> The site want the image to be in CMYK (no specific profile) and 300 dpi.

In general terms, that is a bit dumb, not asking for a specific profile, but seeing your image, that has clearly pure yellow here, and pure cyan there... (at least it looks like it) you need to do it in the native application you used, Photoshop?

And correct the values if you feel they are "contaminated" (for example, be sure the yellow only contains yellow and probably magenta, not cyan, etc.

Use a generic profile in that application, more specific a coated one, like Fogra 39 if it is going to be printed on an inkjet-based system, or SWOP v2 in the US if is going to be printed in sheetfed offset.